# Javascript function 'is not a function' when called in a form

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a simple form-extension script:

```
var counter=1;
function newField(counter) {
    counter++;
    var newFields = document.getElementById('readroot').cloneNode(true);
    newFields.id = "formcheck"+counter;
    newFields.style.display = 'block';
    var newField = newFields.childNodes;
    var insertHere = document.getElementById('writeroot');
    insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
}
```

being called inside of a form:

```
<form id='newanimal' action='/submit' method='post'>    
<span id='writeroot'></span>
<button id='newField' type='button' onclick=newField();>Add Field</button>
</form>
```

`readroot` looks like this:

```
<div id="readroot" style="display: none">

<input type="button" value="Remove review"
            onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode); counter--;" /><br /><br />

<input id="checkform" name="checkform" value="New Checkform" />
</div>
```

Now the function works fine, unless it's called from inside of a form. When executed as-is, I get `newField is not a function` called as an error, however if you remove the form tags and it runs fine.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: check by changing the id of your button 'newField' to some other

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<button id='newField' type='button' onclick=newField();>Add Field</button>
```

When an element has an `id` property, the element is accessible using the global variable of that name.  So your function `newField` is overwritten by a reference to the element with the id `newField`.  Since it is now an HTML element, it is evidently "not a function".

[WhatWG spec for this](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#dom-window-nameditem). Note that this is not behaviour you should rely upon, but you should be wary of it for exactly this reason. Note that unpredictable behaviour in the global scope is a *very* good reason to avoid using the global scope.